# CoreNFC ISO7816 example?

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I'm looking for an example of CoreNFC ISO7816 connecting and reading. Can anybody show me the simplest one? I'm new to iOS dev, and official docs where not helpful for me.
I tried to use **NFCTagReaderSession** class. Its constructor signature is

```
init?(pollingOption: NFCTagReaderSession.PollingOption, delegate: NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue?)
```

**NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate** is a protocol, so I created a class for the implementation:

```
class NFCReaderDelegate: NSObject, NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate {
    func tagReaderSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession) {}
    
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {}
    
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        print("got a Tag!"
        print("\(tags)")
        //let nfcTag = tags.first!
        print("connecting to Tag!")
    }
}
```

So, I've made a func

```
func nfc() -> Void {
let delegate = NFCReaderDelegate()
    let option = NFCTagReaderSession.PollingOption.iso14443
    let session = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: option, delegate: delegate, queue: nil)
//..............
```

As I could understand, the result of the connection as reference to a tag I should see as calling of **tagReaderSession** method of the delegate, but nothing happens.
Next, I tried to call **session.connect(to:)** method manually. It's signature is

```
func connect(to: NFCTag, completionHandler: (Error?) -> Void)
```

But, where can I get **NFCTag** ??

I tried to declare it manually with an expression like `let tag: NFCTag = NFCTag.iso7816()`, but it asks a protocol parameter as well... So, I cannot succeed so far. I need only a simple workable applet.

Comment: Apple has an introductory video on CoreNFC (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/718/) and there is sample code (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app/) have you tried those two things?

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are not often retained so you holding an temporary reference to your variable `delegate` will probably be deallocated and nil as soon as the function `nfc()` completes.

Instead. Make your holding class implement `NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate` or just keep the delegate a instance:

```
// Keep it here to avoid it from being deallocated
let delegate = NFCReaderDelegate()

func nfc() -> Void {
    let option = NFCTagReaderSession.PollingOption.iso14443
    let session = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: option, delegate: delegate, queue: nil)
    //..............
}
```